# appendChild For loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, appendchild

How can I get 5 different squares with Random colors using this method ?
I can get 5 clones but I am trying to have them all different \ ideally different sizes as well but for now I am just trying to get the for loop to work.

```
function get_random_color() {
  function c() {
    var hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
    return ("0" + String(hex)).substr(-2); // pad with zero
  }
  return "#" + c() + c() + c();
}
let random_color = get_random_color();
```

```
const square = document.createElement("div");
square.style.width = "50px";
square.style.height = "50px";
square.style.margin = "10px";
square.style.backgroundColor = get_random_color();
```

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  document.body.appendChild(square);
}
```

Comment: Put the logic for creating `square` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks Henry !  That helped understand step one !